# Flixel - FlxButton is acting as if clicked multiple times

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flixel

I have a couple of dialog screens made from FlxGroups. The first screen, `LandingScreen` has a button that opens a second screen, `CargoShop`. Whenever a screen is added, it is made the active screen in my FlxState, and the other screens' buttons are set to `active = false;` So, when the button to open the `CargoShop` screen is clicked, it is set to `active = false;` at the next update cycle.

Now, the `CargoShop` screen has a button to close it, which makes the `LandingScreen` active again. For some reason, as soon as the `CargoShop` screen is closed, a new one is instantly opened as if the shop button had been clicked again.

These buttons are not on top of each other. Is there some trick I'm missing with FlxButton that is thinks it's clicked when it's not? It only happens when I use the mouse; if I close the `CargoScreen` with a keyboard command, a new one is not instantly created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic truth I've just learned about `FlxGroup`s: Setting a group to active:false != setting each member of the group to active:false.

Say you have a `FlxGroup` with a bunch of `FlxButton`s in it. If you click a button and one of the results is that `FlxGroup` gets set to `active = false`, the button itself is still active.

The solution: call...

```
yourGroup.setAll("active", false);
```

This will set each member of the `FlxGroup` to `active = false`, and the button will know it can't possibly be clicked.

Source: [funstorm](http://www.funstormgames.com/blog/2012/01/flixel-the-trouble-with-removing-buttons-callbacks/) - See solution #2

Answer (score 0):

You can set `mouseEnable = mouseChildren = false` to the non-active screen to make sure it will not receive mouse input. Although your issue seems - at first view - to be a logic trouble.

Comment: Indeed...I think there's a good chance Flixel has a bug that's causing this problem, but I am not sure.